# How to write TestNG annotations like 'before test, before method, before class, after class' for code

Tags: java, unit-testing, automated-tests, testng

I'm new to TestNG notations, can anyone help me with how can I write down TestNG test cases (testing annotations like before test, before method, before class, after class) for the following code.

```
package au.com.junitpractice;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Stack {
 private List<Integer> integerList;
 private List<Integer> maxList;
 private int currentMax;

 public Stack() {
 integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 maxList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 currentMax = 0;
 }

 public void push(int value) {
 integerList.add(value);

 if(this.currentMax < value) {
 this.currentMax = value;
 }
 maxList.add(currentMax);
 }

 public int pop() {
 int popVal = integerList.remove(integerList.size()-1);
 maxList.remove(maxList.size()-1);

 if(!maxList.isEmpty()) {
 currentMax = maxList.get(maxList.size() - 1);
 }
 return popVal;
 }

 public int getMax() {
 //return Collections.max(integerList);
 //return maxList.remove(maxList.size()-1);
 return currentMax;
 }

 public int getSize() {
 return integerList.size();
 }
}
```

Comment: Please refer the official documentation: https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Answer (score 0):

@BeforeTest is used for applying some logic **before**  you are running the test class.
For example in each of your tests to instantiate a Stack object in order to test it, you can do it only one time:

```
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.testng.Assert;

    public class Test_BeforeTestAndBeforeMethod {
    
        @BeforeTest
        public void beforeTestDemo()
        {       
            Stack s = new Stack();   
        } 
    
    @Test
        public void testStack()
        {
    Assert.assertEquals(s.getSize(), 0);
    
        }
}
```

you can read about the rest of the annotations https://www.browserstack.com/guide/testng-annotations-in-selenium
but it is straight forward, for example @BeforeMethod will run before **each method**
and **@AfterTest** will run after your tests(if you want for example to do a cleanup)

Comment: Hi mottig, thank you so much for answering my query.
So just like you created one for ' @BeforeTest', do I need to create the rest of the annotations the same as that?

Comment: No you dont have to use all of these annotations. for example you can use just the @Test and instantiate the stack in the actual testing method (without using the @BeforeTest)